# Good way to access mixed 8/16/32-bit words

Tags: arrays, io, stream, kotlin

I have a big lump of binary data in memory and I need to read/write from randomly accessed, byte-aligned addresses. However, sometimes I need to read/write 8-bit words, sometimes (big-endian) 16-bit words, and sometimes (big-endian) 32-bit ones.

There's the naïve solution of representing the data as a `ByteArray` and implementing 16/32-bit reads/writes by hand:

```
class Blob (val image: ByteArray, var ptr: Int = 0) {
  fun readWord8(): Byte = image[ptr++]

  fun readWord16(): Short {
    val hi = readWord8().toInt() and 0xff
    val lo = readWord8().toInt() and 0xff
    return ((hi shl 8) or lo).toShort()
  }

  fun readWord32(): Int {
    val hi = readWord16().toLong() and 0xffff
    val lo = readWord16().toLong() and 0xffff
    return ((hi shl 16) or lo).toInt()
  }
}
```

(and similarly for `writeWord8`/`writeWord16`/`writeWord32`).

Is there a better way to do this? It just seems so inefficient doing all this byte-shuffling when Java itself already uses big-endian representation inside...

To reiterate, I need **both read and write access**, **random seeks**, and **8/16/32-bit access** to big-endian words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Java NIO `ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html):

```
val array = ByteArray(100)
val buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(array)

val b = buffer.get()
val s = buffer.getShort()
val i = buffer.getInt()

buffer.put(0.toByte())
buffer.putShort(0.toShort())
buffer.putInt(0)

buffer.position(10)
```

The byte order of a newly created `ByteBuffer` is `BIG_ENDIAN`, but it can still be changed with the [`order(ByteOrder)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order(java.nio.ByteOrder)) function.

Also, use [`ByteBuffer.allocate(size)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocate(int)) and [`buffer.array()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array()) if you want to avoid creating a `ByteArray` explicily.

More about `ByteBuffer` usage: [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841340/what-is-the-use-of-bytebuffer-in-java).

Comment: `.postion()` doesn't make a new buffer, just returns the same data wrapped with a different pointer, right? I wouldn't want to keep copying my blob around.

Comment: @Cactus, yep, `buffer.array() === newBuffer.array()` is `true`.

Comment: @Cactus, I've checked the docs for `position` and found that it actually modifies `this` buffer and returns it, so that there's even no need to use the return value. Fixed the answer, sorry.