# What is the purpose of a Buffer in Java?

Tags: java, buffer

Buffer is an abstract class having concrete subclasses such as ByteBuffer, IntBuffer, etc. It seems to be a container of data of a specific primitive type. What are the benefits of a Buffer? Why wouldn't I just use an array or a list?

Comment: Reading the docs should answer this question by highlighting the differences. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4841340/438992

Comment: I see what the methods do. I was wondering what the purpose of a buffer is typically. An alternate version of my question, for clarity, might read "What does the name 'buffer' imply?".

Comment: I guess I'd assumed the purpose was implied by its capabilities ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 10):

A buffer can be defined, in its simplest form, as a contiguous block of memory of some type. Hence a byte buffer of size 4K (4096 bytes) may occupy memory locations `0xf000` through `0xffff` inclusive.

As to why a buffer type may be used instead of an array or list, neither of those two alternatives have the in-built features of `limit`, `position` or `mark`.

On the first item, a buffer separates the `capacity` from the `limit` in that you can have a `capacity` of 1000 with a current `limit` of 10. In other words, it enforces the ability to have a variable size *up to and including* the `capacity`.

For the other two features, the current `position` provides an in-built way to read or write the next element, easing sequential processing, and the `mark` provides a way to save the current `position` for later reset.

All these features would require *extra* variables if you needed them in conjunction with an array or list.

Of course, if you don't *need* any of these features then, by all means, use an array.

Comment: What does the name buffer imply?

Comment: @CowPowPow, a buffer is simply a contiguous block of memory. For example, a ten-byte buffer at memory location 17 occupies the byte addresses from 17 through 26 inclusive. I'll add that to the answer.